# No output with inner join query laravel

Tags: sql, laravel

Im not the best in laravel but i try my best in converting sql to laravel syntax. My Problem is that i cant get an output with the inner join query i wrote.

My Query:

```
  $scores = DB::table('users')
    ->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('devices.id', 'devices.devicename', 'users.name as ausgeliehen von', 'devices.created_at', 'devices.updated_at')
    ->get();
```

My View:

```
<tbody>

  @foreach ($scores as $score)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->devicename}}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->created_at }}</td>
    <td>{{ $score->updated_at }}</td>
```

My Output table looks like this:

Sql query:

```
SELECT devices.id, devices.devicename,users.name, devices.created_at, devices.updated_at
FROM devices
INNER JOIN users ON devices.id = users.id;
```

Output from sql query:

Comment: Your join conditions look suspicious to me.  Why would a user ID and a device ID be related?  Maybe show us your raw MySQL query, and some sample data.

Comment: SELECT devices.id, devices.bezeichnung,users.name, devices.created_at, devices.updated_at
FROM devices
INNER JOIN users ON devices.id = users.id;

Comment: Dont edit the original question and change your query to the working version as it is confusing for people looking for help with this issue in the future. The code should remain the broken version and then the answer that helps you will easily show how to fix it. By you fixing your original code it is hard to realise what is actually happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why you join "ausleihs" table if you don't use it?

```
$scores = DB::table('users')
  ->join('devices', 'devices.id', '=', 'users.id')
  ->select('devices.id', 'devices.bezeichnung', 'users.name as ausgeliehen von', 'devices.created_at', 'devices.updated_at')
  ->get();
```